# Chrome extension Match Pattern for base64 src (or Match Pattern exclusion)

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension, base64, match

I'm building a chrome extension, and  would like to set up a distinct contextMenu (added element to right click menu) for images that have their src encoded as base64 data instead of a url.

I can successfully filter urls (here, jpgs) using the 'Match Pattern' syntax with targetUrlPatterns https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  'title' : 'This is a jpeg',
  'type' : 'normal',
  'targetUrlPatterns':['*://*/*.jpg', '*://*/*.jpeg'],
  'contexts' : ['image'],
  'onclick' : getClickHandler()
});
```

I can't, however, figure out a way to match base 64 src's, since they don't follow the standard url format that Match Pattern seems to require.

For example, i'd like to identify image src's like the following:

> src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQSEhUUEhQWFRUWFBQVFBQ...

but cant figure out a good way to do so with the documentation for Match Pattern.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  'title' : 'This is a data url',
  'type' : 'normal',
  'targetUrlPatterns':['*data ... ???'],
  'contexts' : ['image'],
  'onclick' : getClickHandler()
});
```

Edit: It would also be a win to exclude any images that are *not* jpegs to avoid the base64 matching problem altogether, however Match Pattern syntax doesn't seem to have an exclusion pattern.

Comment: I'm afraid that's probably impossible.